# How to use dialogflow Client In Python

Tags: python, client, dialogflow-es

what i am trying is to get the response in python

```
import dialogflow
from google.api_core.exceptions import InvalidArgument

DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID = 'imposing-fx-333333'
DIALOGFLOW_LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = 'imposing-fx-333333-e6e3cb9e4adb.json'
text_to_be_analyzed = "Hi! I'm David and I'd like to eat some sushi, can you help me?"
session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()
session = session_client.session_path(DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID, SESSION_ID)
text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(text=text_to_be_analyzed, 
language_code=DIALOGFLOW_LANGUAGE_CODE)
query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)
try:
    response = session_client.detect_intent(session=session, query_input=query_input)
except InvalidArgument:
    raise
print("Query text:", response.query_result.query_text)
print("Detected intent:", response.query_result.intent.display_name)
print("Detected intent confidence:", response.query_result.intent_detection_confidence)
print("Fulfillment text:", response.query_result.fulfillment_text)
```

And i am getting unable to verify credentials

```
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
```

This is my first question in stackoverflow :) i know i have done many

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to export **Service Account Key (JSON)** file from your , and set an environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to the file path of the JSON file that contains your service account key. Then you can make call to dialogflow.

**Steps to get Service Account Key:**
Make sure you are using Dialogflow v2.
Go to general settings and click on your Service Account. This will redirect you to Google Cloud Platform project’s service account page.
Next step is to create a new key for the service account. Now create a service account and choose JSON as output key. Follow the instructions and a JSON file will be downloaded to your computer. This file will be used as `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`.

Now in code,

```
import os
import dialogflow
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "/path/to/file.json"
project_id = "your_project_id"
session_id = "your_session_id"
language_code = "en"
session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()
session = session_client.session_path(project_id, session_id)

text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(text=text, language_code=language_code)
query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)
response_dialogflow = session_client.detect_intent(session=session, query_input=query_input)
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works too in case you want to pick up the file from file system.
Recomended way is using env variables thoguh

`import json
    from google.cloud import dialogflow_v2
    from google.oauth2 import *
session_client = None
dialogflow_key = None
creds_file = "/path/to/json/file.json"

dialogflow_key = json.load(open(creds_file))
credentials = (service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(dialogflow_key))

session_client = dialogflow_v2.SessionsClient(credentials=credentials)

print("it works : " + session_client.DEFAULT_ENDPOINT) if session_client is not None 
else print("does not work")`

I forgot to add the main article sorry...
Here it is :

https://googleapis.dev/python/google-auth/latest/user-guide.html#service-account-private-key-files